# How to get a list of devices enumerated in Explorer network using C++

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, ssdp, wsd

As shown in the attached photo, I would like to obtain a list of devices on the same subnet that appear in Explorer-Network using C++.

What API can I use to obtain specific navigation methods such as WSD, NetBIOS, and SSDP?

If you have a specific code example, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You could try to use [WNetOpenEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetopenenuma) to [enumerate Network Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources)